# How to remove negative sign from LINQ output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

i have following linq used in my application

```
var FinalSubExpired = subExpired.Where(e => (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(e.AreasOfLawTillDate)).TotalDays <= 30 ).ToList();
```

which returns the total days with negative values, i need to remove that negative sign from that total days. how can i do that by modifying this linq?

Please help.

Comment: What is it you are trying to calculate? Also, your linq output will be a list of whatever `subExpired` is... so where does the negative value come in?

Comment: All those who down voted my question please give solution to this also
By default when my Ckeditor starts "JustifyBlock" toolbar button must be in a selected mode, How can i select JustifyBlock ckeditor toolbar button by default? Where should i specify this in CK editor?

And thos who dont get the question check the answers provided below by b_meyer and Sanjeev. Thats what i am looking for.

Comment: The fact that someone managed to stumble across the correct answer doesn't negate the fact that others had queries that they felt the original question didn't address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var FinalSubExpired = subExpired.Where(e => Math.Abs((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(e.AreasOfLawTillDate)).TotalDays) <= 30).ToList();
```

that should do the trick

Comment: All this will do is filter out results that are <= 30 if they are < -30.

Comment: @b_meyer. that was the right way to get it, Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

try and use `Math.Abs` inside your Linq query, as:

```
var FinalSubExpired = subExpired.Where(e => (Math.Abs(DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(e.AreasOfLawTillDate)).TotalDays) <= 30 ).ToList();
```

Comment: yup...same answer, that shows most of the developers think in the same way nothing else!